# How do I learn this "any ... func" code?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, extension-methods, func, any

I with could re-write the question better, but can someone tell me where I can learn what is happening in this piece of azure code?
[image]

Comment: What dont you understand? Look at the MSDN docs, aka F1.

Comment: What is the technology involved?  What's the name?  I know Generics, but there is more there than that.  I'm not sure what to search for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code has about three non-basic concepts in it:

- [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)

  > Extension methods enable you to "add" methods to existing types without creating a new derived type, recompiling, or otherwise modifying the original type.
- [LINQ (Language-Integrated Query)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx)

  > Language-Integrated Query (LINQ) is a set of features introduced in Visual Studio 2008 that extends powerful query capabilities to the language syntax of C# and Visual Basic.
- [Lambda Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

  > A lambda expression is an anonymous function that can contain expressions and statements, and can be used to create delegates or expression tree types.

Answer (score 2):

It simply returns true if one of the items in the changes collections is a RoleConfigurationSettingChange.

This is one of the LINQ extension methods and has nothing to do with Azure.

Answer (score 2):

This method is checking to see if any of the changes passed into the `RoleEnvironmentChanging` method are a configuration change.

By looking at the list of changes, it uses the `.Any` method to see if any of the changes are of the type `RoleEnvironmentConfigurationSettingsChange`.

Answer (score 1):

Further reading ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx

Its essentially saying if that if there are any changes of type specified then execute the body of the if statement.

Hope that helps